# Bounding $A(n,d)=\max\{M|$exists a code with parameters $n$,$M$,$d\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I would like to prove that this lower bound of $A(n,d)=\max\{M|$exists a code with parameters $n$,$M$,$d$$\}$ (where $n$ is the length of the block code, $M$ the number of words of the code, and $d$, the minimal distance of the code), holds: $$\frac{2^{n}}{\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}{n\choose i}}\leq A(n,d)$$

For trying to see this, I have tried to connect this inequality with the cardinal of the ball of radius $d-1$, that is $\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}{n\choose i} 2^{i}$, so for sure, that quantity is less than $2^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}{n\choose i}$. But I don't see if this is or not helping me at all... I would appreciate some guidance, help, hint,... Thanks!

**Note** I am working over a binary alphabet

Comment: Looks like the Hamming bound.

Comment: In my notes, the hamming bound is: $q^{n}\geq M(\sum_{i=0}^{t} {n\choose i} (q-1)^{i}$, with $\mathcal{C}$ being a block code of length $n$, over an alphabet of $q$ elements and a correction capacity of $t$. In this particular case, where $q=2$, I don't see how that would give me a lower bound, eventhough it for sure gives me an upper bound of $A(n,d)$

Comment: @Wuestenfux Actually, it is the Gilbert-Varshamov lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there!  Note that the sphere of Hamming radius $t$ has $\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\binom{n}{i}$ vectors in it, not $\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\binom{n}{i}2^i$ vectors as you state.

Suppose that there are spheres of Hamming radius $d-1$ centered at the $M$ codewords in a $(n,M,d)$ code. Some of these spheres might be overlapping (i.e., not disjoint) but never mind that. The *total* volume occupied by these $M$ spheres (ignoring the overlap) is $M\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\binom{n}{i}$. Now, if it so happens
$$M\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\binom{n}{i} < 2^n,\tag{1}$$
then there is at least one vector in the binary $n$-space that is, by construction, at distance $d$ or more from *all* the $M$ codewords that we started with. So, we can include this vector in our code to create a $(n,M+1,d)$ code. Lather, rinse, and repeat. We now have a $(n,M+1,d)$ code for  which we can test whether
$$(M+1)\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\binom{n}{i} < 2^n\tag{2}$$
holds or not. If $(2)$ holds, we can add another codeword to construct a
$(n,M+2,d)$ code, and repeat the whole process again.

We stop when we reach a point where we have a $(n,M^\prime, d)$ code for which the inequality reverses:
$$M^\prime \sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\binom{n}{i} \geq 2^n$$
and we can no longer apply the above argument. We could *try* to see if more sophisticated thinking and reasoning about the overlap between spheres that we totally ignored might improve the result, but we won't: many people have already tried without much success. But, we have shown that there exists a $(n,M^\prime, d)$ code such that

$$M^\prime \sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\binom{n}{i} \geq 2^n \implies M^\prime \geq \dfrac{2^n}{\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\binom{n}{i}}.$$
It follows that $$A(n,d) \geq \dfrac{2^n}{\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\binom{n}{i}}$$
which is the result you are trying to prove.

Comment: Thanks! Very clear, now I get it! :)